# Linux - How to add driver to selenium standalone?

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have an Ubuntu server and up there I have a JAR file Selenium standalone.

Whenever I want to test website via Firefox, I have to run the Selenium with an added param `Dwebdriver.firefox.bin`, otherwise, I will get an error saying that WebDriver cannot find the binary path for Firefox (though it is installed under `/usr/bin/firefox`)

My question is, is there a way not to use that param?

Comment: Yes, you need to installed it into default location, then run jar without added param `webdriver.firefox.bin`, it will take firefox from default automatically..Thanks..:)

Comment: Selenium is looking for the firefox binary in the pathes of the PATH environment variable. Make sure that /usr/bin is in the path of the session that is running the jar file.